# Can sudden thermal contraction fix hail dents?

Tags: thermodynamics

I recently bought a car with some hail damage, and someone told me that you can fix the exterior dents by throwing ice on (for instance) the dented hood. I'm a bit skeptical of fixing dents caused by ice by applying more ice, but I wonder if it could work. Currently, I live in Phoenix where it isn't uncommon to see outside temperatures above $110^\circ$F ($43 ^\circ$C). If you did throw ice on the hood, would the thermal contraction  be enough to fix (or at least reduce) the hail damage? Would there be any other side effects?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a homeopathic remedy. :)

Comment: That's a pretty simple experiment, isn't it? The outcome probably depends on the type of the deformation. Most videos on Youtube seem to show professionals using other methods and folks who tried it with cooling couldn't get it to work...

Comment: Considering that the original hail damage to the car was caused by throwing ice (hail) onto the sheet metal, it is unlikely that more of the same will cause the damage to magically disappear.

Comment: I like the question, but agree that it probably should go to an ENGINEERING site ... perhaps it's DRY-ICE [i.e., frozen carbon-dioxide] which will do the trick ??